# Why does the number of nodes keep increasing in neo4j even though we don't create any nodes?

Tags: neo4j, nodes, cypher

This is the number of nodes before I create the new one:

```
neo4j-sh (0)$ match n return n;
==> +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
==> | n                                                                      |
==> +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
==> | Node[0]{}                                                              |
==> | Node[1]{address:"rioeduardo92@gmail.com",comment:"home",person_id:"1"} |
==> | Node[2]{address:"rioeduardo92@yahoo.com",comment:"work",person_id:"1"} |
==> | Node[3]{person_id:"1",name:"Rio"}                                      |
==> +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

after I created the new one, the node that I just created is started from node number 300:

```
neo4j-sh (0)$ create (n:lolo{color:'blue'}) return n;
==> +-------------------------+
==> | n                       |
==> +-------------------------+
==> | Node[300]{color:"blue"} |
==> +-------------------------+
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the number of nodes increasing but the internal node id. If you created a lot of nodes and deleted them for example, then your new node might have taken up the next highest id (300) because the old id's haven't been recycled yet. 
Which is why you should never count on the internal node ID to serve as an identifier/key on your nodes.

```
start n=node(*) return count(n)
```

should give you the true number of nodes in your graph

Comment: Thank you so much Luanne for your explaination.